# registerHibernateType in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

What is registerHibernateType and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerHibernateType%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29

```
Registers a Hibernate Type name for the given Types type code and maximum column length.

Parameters:
  code - The Types typecode
  capacity - The maximum length of database type
  name - The Hibernate Type name
```